# QuerySet values() method behaviour

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Consider the query:

```
Blog.objects.values('id', 'author')
```

it returns a dictionary:

```
[{'id': 1, 'author': 1234}]
```

Is there a way to obtain instance objects for those fields that are actually foreignkeys? E.g. I'd like something like:

```
[{'id': 1, 'author': <User instance>}]
```

Clarification: I'm actually using `.values()` in a more complex query in conjunction with `.annotate()`, therefore I need to use `.values()` to GROUP BY records.

Answer (score 0):

`.values()` returns values, not objects.
You can do something like this:

```
values = [{'id': 1, 'author': 1234}, {'id': 2, 'author': 2345}]
authors_ids = [v['author'] for v in values]
authors_qs = Author.objects.filter(id__in=author_ids)
```

And then replace `author` by object:

```
for v in values:
    for author in authors_qs:
        if v['author'] == author.id:
            v['author'] = author
```

Sure, if there are many objects, two loops may cause speed problems, but you get an idea.